# Как редактировать значение глобальной переменной в lua?

Tags: lua

Разрабатываю кастомку в Доте 2, работаю в lua. Что нужно сделать, чтобы отредактировать значение глобальной переменной? Например, изначально в variable.lua a = 0, но когда какая-либо функция в test.lua изменит её значение на 1, то а = 0 в variable.lua перезапишется на а = 1. Мне это нужно для сохранения у игрока его лучшего результата

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема то? Если я не ошибаюсь, то глобальная переменная общая для всех файлов. Если ее объявить в 1 файле, а в 2 файле изменить, то она измениться и для 1.